# Modifying final column value in SAS by group

Tags: arrays, loops, sas

I have the following data set:

```
Student         TestDayStart        TestDayEnd
001             1                   5
001             6                   10
001             11                  15
002             1                   4
002             5                   9
002             10                  14
```

I would like to make the last 'TestDayEnd' the final value for 'TestDayStart' for each Student.
So the data should look like this:

```
Student         TestDayStart        TestDayEnd
001             1                   5
001             6                   10
001             11                  15
001             15                  15
002             1                   4
002             5                   9
002             10                  14
002             14                  14
```

I'm not quite sure how I can do this in SAS. Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After sorting the dataset you can do this within a data step.

```
proc sort data=have;
by student testdaystart testdayend;
run;
```

Now you can use the `by` and `retain` statements in the data step. The `by` statement allows you to find the last student, and the `retain` statement lets you keep the previous value in the dataset.

```
data want;
set have;
retain last_testdayend;
by student testdaystart testdayend;
output;
last_testdayend = testdayend;
if last.student then do;
    if testdaystart ne testdayend then do;
        testdaystart = last_testdayend;
        testdayend = last_testdayend;
        output; * this second output statement creates a new record in the dataset;
    end;
end;
drop last_testdayend;
run;
```